# access variable in so file and register callback function in ctypes

Tags: python, c++, c, ctypes, wrapper

I'm trying to access variable declared in cpp header file from the compiled shared object.
Below is my case

**/*cpp_header.hpp*/**

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//variables declaration
const uint8_t variable1 = 3;
const uint16_t variable2 = 4056;
const uint16_t variable3 = 3040;

typedef struct {
    void* a;
    uint32_t b
    uint16_t w;
    uint16_t h;
    size_t p;
} structure1 ;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b
} structure2 ;

//callback function declaration
typedef void (*one_callback) (const structure1 *);
typedef void (*output_callback) (const structure1 *);
typedef void (*inpout_callback) (const structure2 *);

//APIs using the callback function
int start_api(enum_type, output_callback, inpout_callback);
```

What i'm trying in ctypes

**/*ctype_wrapper.py*/**

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

lib_instance = CDLL('test.so')

#accessing the variable declared in cpp header
variable1 = c_uint8.in_dll(lib_instance, 'variable1')
variable2 = c_uint16.in_dll(lib_instance, 'variable2')
variable3 = c_uint16.in_dll(lib_instance, 'variable2')

//registering callback function
ctype_start_api = lib_instance.start_api
ctype_start_api.argtypes = [enum_type, output_callback, inpout_callback] # register the callback
ctype_start_api.restype = c_int
```

**Error output**

```
#error for variable access
File "ctype_wrapper.py", line 6, in <module>
    variable1 = c_uint8.in_dll(lib_instance, 'variable1')
ValueError: ./test.so: undefined symbol: variable1
```

For callback register, i referred the ctypes document but no idea how to implement that for my scenario.

Is my variable declaration is correct in header.hpp file or i need to add anything to get export the variables in compiled so file?

Comment: Just don't do spaghetti programming with globals declared all over the place. There is never a reason to declare a variable inside a header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables and function in must be exported for `ctypes` to find them.  `extern` may be sufficient on Linux to export variables, but on Windows both variables and functions need an additional `__declspec(dllexport)` declaration.

`ctypes` also expects exported variables and functions to be C linkage, so C++ variables and functions need to be wrapped in `extern "C"`.

Here's a working example, tested on Windows, that also demonstrates callbacks:

**test.hpp**

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

typedef struct {
    void* a;
    uint32_t b;
    uint16_t w;
    uint16_t h;
    size_t p;
} structure1;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
} structure2;

typedef void (*output_callback) (const structure1 *);
typedef void (*inpout_callback) (const structure2 *);

extern "C" {

API extern const uint8_t variable1;
API extern const uint16_t variable2;
API extern const uint16_t variable3;

API int start_api(output_callback, inpout_callback);

}
```

**test.cpp**

```cpp
#include "test.hpp"

extern "C" {

const uint8_t variable1 = 3;
const uint16_t variable2 = 4056;
const uint16_t variable3 = 3040;

int start_api(output_callback ocb, inpout_callback iocb) {
    structure1 s1 { nullptr, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    structure2 s2 { 5, 6 };
    if(ocb)
        ocb(&s1);
    if(iocb)
        iocb(&s2);
    return 0;
}

}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct

class Structure1(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('a', ct.c_void_p),
                ('b', ct.c_uint32),
                ('w', ct.c_uint16),
                ('h', ct.c_uint16),
                ('p', ct.c_size_t))
    # Good habit: print representation of class so it can print itself.
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Structure1(a={self.a}, b={self.b}, w={self.w}, h={self.h}, p={self.p})'

class Structure2(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('a', ct.c_uint32),
                ('b', ct.c_uint32))
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Structure2(a={self.a}, b={self.b})'

OCB = ct.CFUNCTYPE(None, ct.POINTER(Structure1))
IOCB = ct.CFUNCTYPE(None, ct.POINTER(Structure2))

# decorating a function with the callback signature makes it callable from C
@OCB
def output_callback(ps1):
    print(ps1.contents)

@IOCB
def inpout_callback(ps2):
    print(ps2.contents)

lib_instance = ct.CDLL('./test')
start_api = lib_instance.start_api
start_api.argtypes = OCB, IOCB
start_api.restype = ct.c_int

variable1 = ct.c_uint8.in_dll(lib_instance, 'variable1')
variable2 = ct.c_uint16.in_dll(lib_instance, 'variable2')
variable3 = ct.c_uint16.in_dll(lib_instance, 'variable3')

print(variable1.value, variable2.value, variable3.value)
start_api(output_callback, inpout_callback)
```

Output:

```
3 4056 3040
Structure1(a=None, b=1, w=2, h=3, p=4)
Structure2(a=5, b=6)
```

Comment: how do we pass 'NULL' for one of function in callbacks? For example: I want to pass only 'inpout_callback' function in 'start_api' callback. like start_api(NULL, inpout_callback)

Comment: @soundarrajanv pass `None` for NULL.

Comment: I tried that but i'm getting below error,
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_app.py", line 54, in <module>
   lib_instance.op_start(mode_2, None, input_callback)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: expected CFunctionType instance instead of NoneType```

Comment: @soundarrajanv Not in front of a computer right now, but try `start_api.argtypes = ct.POINTER(OCB), ct.POINTER(IOCB)`, then use `None`

Comment: yeah tried as you suggested but **getting segmentation fault**. ```lib_instance.op_start(mode_2, None, input_callback)```. Since input_callback is pointer now, so when trying to access throwing segmentation fault. 
So, any other way to try?

Comment: @soundarrajanv Change argtypes back, and try `OCB(None)` to create a null function pointer. Oh and your original API had 3 arguments so make sure argtypes matches

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_app.py", line 54, in <module>
    lib_instance.op_start(mode_2, output_callback(None), input_callback)
TypeError: argument must be callable or integer function address``` am i doing it correctly?

Comment: @soundarrajanv Finally in front of a computer.  The error message when `OCB(None)` was used was `TypeError: argument must be callable or integer function address`, so `OCB(0)` was what was needed.  That creates the right function pointer type but with a null value.  That object works with my sample code above for the output callback.

Comment: In the output you are returning None for 'a' **Structure1(a=None,**, But i need a address to be returned for c_void_p variable. Because it is buffer in real case. So i need to access the ptr address. Is there any way?

Comment: @soundarrajanv Use `ctypes.cast`

Answer (score 1):

In the header change

```
const uint8_t variable1 = 3;
```

to

```
extern const uint8_t variable1;
```

And add this

```
extern const uint8_t variable1 = 3;
```

to a .cpp file

By default `const` variables have internal linkage in C++, so won't be exported from a shared library.

Comment: Remove `extern` from the last example.

Comment: @Lundin Why? Wouldn't that just reintroduce the same problem.

Comment: Because you'll want it to compile?

Comment: @Lundin The code compiles perfectly well in C++, not sure about C, but I did say in a .cpp file.

Comment: I could imagine that the declaration in the header file is superfluous. The explanation is totally right though, the constants have internal linkage.